# Cakephp3.x Sessions across sub domains

Tags: php, cookies, cakephp-3.0

I know this type of question has been posted here but i want the solution for this in cakephp3.x. I have multiple sub domains and I'm trying to use the sessions across sub domains.

```
 http://example.com
 http://xyz.example.com
 http://abc.example.com
```

From other stack-overflow article i come know that i have set the cookie domain  as below

```
session.cookie_domain = ".example.com"
```

But i don't find a way where and how to to set this in cakpehp3.x

Comment: I did this inside app controller initialize method  $this->loadComponent('Cookie', ['httpOnly' => true,'domain'=>'.example.com']);

Comment: Have you checked the docs? There's an examaple showing exactly that. **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#session-configuration**

Answer (score 1):

First of all thank you @ndm for your solution. I have to put this code inside bootstrap.php

```
Configure::write('Session', [
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'ini' => [
        'session.cookie_path' => '/',
        'session.cookie_domain' => '.yourdomain.com'
    ]
]);
```

And its working for me now.